# Manipulation of variables to obtain a specific equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$0 = h + Rtanθ - \frac{gR^2}{2V_0^2Cos^2θ}$

And I need to solve for R and get this final equation:

$R = \Biggr(1 + \sqrt{1+\frac{2gh}{V_0^2Sin^2θ}}\Biggr)\Biggr(\frac{V_0^2}{2g}\Biggr)$

I have been trying to manipulate R, but I can't get to the final result I am looking for. This is what I do:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to reach the desired equation? I feel I might be complicating it and the answer is right in front of me, but I am too blind to see it.

Comment: What is $v_\theta$?

Comment: @caverac my bad, I have fixed it. It is supposed to be velocity initial

Comment: You can plug in some numbers and will find these two equations are not consistent

Comment: @caverac which two specifically?

Comment: For example, set $h=2$, $g=1$,  $v_0=1/2$ and $\theta = 0.5$, the second equation gives you $R=1.17583$

$$
R=\left(1 + \sqrt{1 + \frac{2gh}{v_0^2\sin^2\theta}}\right)\left(\frac{v_0^2}{2g}\right) = 1.17583
$$

if you replace that value into the first equation, you get

$$
h + R\tan\theta - \frac{gR^2}{2v_0^2\cos^2\theta} = -0.94553 \not= 0
$$

So, the first two equations are not consistent with each other